# Android: Back key press to stop following activity

Tags: android, background

At the beginning, I would like to apologize for my bad English.

There is my problem:

Below timer is showing message at every 3 second , but when i getting out from the program (using back button) the message still pop out.

```
 public Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable(){        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);}
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
         public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing 3 Seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
              });
            }
        }

};
```

i already use `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);` still can't stop it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The call has been made from a runnable thread class, which is still active when Back button is pressed. It will pop messages until the application destroys.
Instead, use this:

```
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

In the docs for removeCallbacksAndMessages it says. here is the link:
[developer website documentation link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

"Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed."

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and after searching a lot, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844433/1952459).

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

would only stop pending messages (Runnables). It won't work for the currently running runnable. You will have to write your own class to stop the currently running runnable.