# Android Runnable not stopping after removeCallbacks()

Tags: android, runnable

I am trying to stop Runnable using removeCallbacks, but somehow it wont stop. - here are my variables

```
 private int mInterval = 2000; // 2 seconds by default, can be changed later
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

and my runnable

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

                checkPayNow();

        } finally {
            // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
            // your update method throws an exception
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    }
};
```

and the method I am running untill it gives me a certain value then i stop

```
public void checkPayNow(){

    if (!url.isEmpty()){

        //url now has text

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }else {
        //no text yet
    }


}
```

Comment: where are you calling checkPayNow for the first time?

Comment: Im calling the Runnable On a Button Click

Comment: You are getting the error because no matter if you cancel it in `checkPayNow()` or not, you are calling `postDelayed()` on your handler anyway via your `finally` block (which you point out in your comment too).

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5844433/6778400 hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean stoped = false;

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {    
             checkPayNow();
        } finally {
           if(!stoped)
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    }
};
```

Make `stoped = true` when you want to stop.

and remove handler from `checkPayNow()`.

```
public void checkPayNow(){

    if (!url.isEmpty()){
        //url now has text
        //mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }else {
        //no text yet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it without `removeCallbacks` like this:

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!checkPayNow()) {
//if not ready so far, then check in some delay again
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    }
};

public boolean checkPayNow(){

    return !url.isEmpty();


}
```