# How to stop Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, scheduled-tasks

I have:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

that runs a runnable task:

```
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But it appears that `executorService` doesn't have a cancel method (wtf, why?), shutting it down isn't an option and I'm doing something fairly simple so using `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` (which does have `cancel()`) is a bit of an overkill.

Is there a way to properly stop the execution of the task?

PS: I searched before I asked and I really don't think this [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844308/removecallbacks-not-stopping-runnable/5844433#5844433) is the correct way.

Comment: You are looking for one of the `shutDown*()` methods.

Comment: I have only `shutdownNow` and `shutDown` from `executorService` and both will also prevent future tasks, but I want future tasks. @fge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` returns a `ScheduledFuture<V>`, which does have a [`cancel(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) method.
The correct way to cancel it is to cancel it through the future.

EDIT: However I believe this cannot stop a task while it is executing, only prevent future executions. Using the boolean flag requires the task to be aware of the `Thread.isInterrupted()` system.

Comment: So I should have a data member for `ScheduledFuture<?>` and populate it when calling `scheduleAtFixedRate`? because I need to stop the task from the task itself which is in the runnable wrapper.

Comment: If the only thing you need is the ability to cancel, just throw an exception from within the `.run()` method. The contract explicitly says this will stop any future executions.

Comment: But that's not what exceptions are for no? and exceptions are considered "runtime heavy" so isn't this little expensive?

Comment: If you don't want to use exceptions then you'll need some sort of wrapper that makes the outer future available to the task, but that will be its own sort of pain implementing.

Comment: will this remove the task from the scheduler . Or will this only make the the `isDone()` method return true. I am asking this because I am using `ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
         ScheduledFuture<?>  future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate`